# Error while calling d3-tip "tip.show" from inside a function

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

> Uncaught TypeError: e.getScreenCTM is not a function while executing the following:

```
 .on('click', function (d) {
            tip.show(d)
            //some more functionality
  })
```

OR

```
 .on('click', function (d) {
            tip.show(d, document.getElementById("head"))
            //some more functionality
  })
```

OR

```
 .on('click', function(d, i) {
   tip.show(d, i)
 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Answer:

```
  .on('click', function (d) {
        tip.show(d, this)
        //other functionality
   })
```